# Как сделать вывод из функции showMiniCart (имя, стоимость и количество добавленного товара)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
function  goodsOut(data) {
    //вывод на страницу
    console.log(data);
    let out = '';
    for(let key in data) {
        out +='<div class="cart">';
        out +=`<img class="cart-img" src="images/${data[key].img}" alt="">`;
        out +=`<h2 class="cart-name">${data[key].name}</h2>`;
        out +=`<p class="cost">${data[key].cost} ${data[key].currency}</p>`;
        out +=`<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="${key}">Купить</button>`;
        out +='</div>';

    }
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', addToCart);
}

    function addToCart() {
        //добавляем товар в корзину

        let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        //console.log(id)

        if( cart[id] == undefined) {
            cart[id] = 1; // если в корзине нет товара - делаем равным 1
        }
        else {
            cart[id]++; // если такой товар есть - увеличиваем на единицу
        }
        showMiniCart();
        saveCart();
    }
    function saveCart() {
        //сохранить корзину
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart)); // корзину в сторку
    }



    function showMiniCart() {
        //показываю мини корзину
        let out = '';
        for (let key in cart) {
            out += key + ' : '  + cart[key] + '<br>';
        }
        $('.mini-cart').html( out);
    }

    function loadCart() {
        //проверка есть ли в localStorage запись cart
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')){
            // если есть - расшифровываю и записываю в переменную cart
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
            showMiniCart();
        }
    }


$(document).ready(function () {
   init();
   loadCart();
});`введите сюда код`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте по аналогии с функцией  goodsOut(data):

```
function loadCart() {
    //проверка есть ли в localStorage запись cart
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        // Здесь у вас судя по всему грузится содержимое корзины в переменную cart 
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        // Передайте её в качестве аргумента функции showMiniCart
        showMiniCart(cart);
    }
}

// В функции showMiniCart обозначаем что она принимает аргумент
function showMiniCart(cart) {
    //показываю мини корзину
    let out = '';
    for (let key in cart) {
        // Здесь собираете блок который надо вывод по аналогии с функцией goodsOut(data)
        out += key + ' : '  + cart[key] + '<br>';
    }
    // Здесь в блок .mini-cart записывается собранный блок
    $('.mini-cart').html(out);
}
```